# Window.resizeTo() not working

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I need to increase the size of my dialog box on some event firing for that I am using `Window.resizeTo()` method in GWT but it is not working. I read its note that

> "In Chrome, this method only works with windows created by
>   Window.open()".

Can someone suggest what I am missing?

Comment: Can you post some code ? It would be easier to help with some code samples.

Comment: @Arti you need post your code that's we can help you .

Comment: Well, have you created the window with `window.open()`?

Comment: @A.Goutam Please use code formatting to format code only.

Comment: No I have my GUI in which I have 10 radio buttons listed vertically, you can take an example with the image i this link "http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaImages/SmartGWT-DraggableWindow.PNG" (sry i dont know how to paste image here). on load if number of radio buttons increases to 50 at that time I am using window.resizeTo() method which is not changing the window size.

Comment: @Juhana ok i will keep in mind for next time

Comment: LOC using is Window.resizeTo(Window.getClientWidth(), Window.getClientHeight()+200);

Comment: Use the correct tags please. This is only a smartgwt question.

Comment: NOTE: In most modern browsers, this method only works with windows created by Window.open() with a supplied width and height.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use window.resizeTo if you are using DialogBox. Because DialogBox doesn't open a new browser window. This creates a modal TABLE-Element.

The table is styled as following:

```
element.style {
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: visible;
  position: absolute;
  left: 600px;
  top: 174px;
  clip: rect(auto auto auto auto);
}
```

A form of popup that has a caption area at the top and can be dragged by the user. Unlike a PopupPanel, calls to PopupPanel.setWidth(String) and PopupPanel.setHeight(String) will set the width and height of the dialog box itself, even if a widget has not been added as yet.

See the [documentation](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DialogBox.html) for more information.

**If you are not using DialogBox. Use DialogBox instead of a browser popup. (this can't be blocked from popup blocker)**